# SQL Server : select every day of a range if there are no days in a table with condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `RRHH.ReportAssistence` in SQL Server. All data is complete automatically from my software for mark and this software is complete that table.

```
cod_mark (int auto increment)
cod_personal (int)
cod_schedule (int) 
date_mark (date) 
check_in (time(0)) 
check_out (time(0))
```

Query:

```
select * from RRHH.ReportAssistence

cod_mark / cod_personal / cod_schedule / date_mark / check_in / check_out    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-02 / NULL     / 18:10:00    
2        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-05 / NULL     / 18:02:00
3        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-08 / 09:20:00 /  NULL   
4        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-10 / NULL     / 18:04:00
5        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-20 / 08:56:00 / 18:53:00
6        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-21 / 08:52:00 / 18:10:00
7        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-22 / 08:56:00 / 18:09:00
8        / 39           /   1          /2017-03-23 / NULL     / 18:05:00
```

I need a stored procedure that lists all days of a range and complete all days range if not exist any "date_mark" display temporally column "CONDITION" = LEFT, if time is in "check_in" up to 09:15:00 display "CONDITION" = LATE, if less to 09:15:00 display "CONTIDION" = OK, if not have check_in "CONDITION" = LEFT IN,
if not have check_out not have problem "CONDITION" = OK

Desired result:

```
SP_showMeReportAssistance (cod_personal), (startDate), (endDate)

execute SP_showMeReportAssistance 39, '01/03/2017', '23/03/2017'

cod_personal / cod_schedule / date_mark / check_in / check_out / CONDITION

39           /   1         /2017-03-01 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT   
39           /   1         /2017-03-02 / NULL     / 18:10:00   / LEFT IN
39           /   1         /2017-03-03 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT   
39           /   1         /2017-03-04 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT   
39           /   1         /2017-03-05 / NULL     / 18:02:00   / LEFT IN
39           /   1         /2017-03-06 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT   
39           /   1         /2017-03-07 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT   
39           /   1         /2017-03-08 / 09:20:00 / NULL       / LATE
39           /   1         /2017-03-09 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT   
39           /   1         /2017-03-10 / NULL     / 18:04:00   / LEFT IN
39           /   1         /2017-03-11 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-12 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-13 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-14 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-15 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-16 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-17 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-18 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-19 / NULL     / NULL       / LEFT
39           /   1         /2017-03-20 / 08:56:00 / 18:53:00   / OK
39           /   1         /2017-03-21 / 08:52:00 / 18:10:00   / OK
39           /   1         /2017-03-22 / 08:56:00 / 18:09:00   / OK
39           /   1         /2017-03-23 / NULL     / 18:05:00   / LEFT IN
```

Comment: How to give cod_schedule for dates not present in ReportAssistence?

Comment: The first table I show is the real one, this information is filled automatically by the software, about "cod_schedule" is the schedule code assigned to the staff which matches the personnel code

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for the remark, but this is just an example of my question, since the names of the tables and columns have changed them for security =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate Date list first based on dates passed to procedure. And do `LEFT JOIN` to your actual Table. And get your CONDITION column by supplying your condition to the `CASE`.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE ReportAssistence (
    cod_mark INT IDENTITY
    ,cod_personal INT
    ,cod_schedule INT
    ,date_mark DATE
    ,check_in TIME(0)
    ,check_out TIME(0)
    )


INSERT INTO ReportAssistence

SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-02' , NULL , '18:10:00'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-05' , NULL , '18:02:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-08' , '09:20:00' , NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-10' , NULL , '18:04:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-20' , '08:56:00' , '18:53:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-21' , '08:52:00' , '18:10:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-22' , '08:56:00' , '18:09:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 39 , 1 ,'2017-03-23' , NULL , '18:05:00'
```

And your code will be

```
DECLARE @cod_personal INT = 39
    ,@startDate DATE = '2017/03/01'
    ,@endDate DATE = '2017/03/23'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, number, @startDate) AS DATES
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE TYPE = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(DD, number, @startDate) <= @endDate
    )
SELECT ISNULL(RA.cod_personal, @cod_personal) AS cod_personal
    ,cod_schedule
    ,DATES AS date_mark
    ,check_in
    ,check_out
    ,CASE 
        WHEN date_mark IS NULL
            THEN 'LEFT'
        WHEN date_mark IS NOT NULL AND check_in IS NULL
            THEN 'LEFT IN'
        WHEN date_mark IS NOT NULL AND check_in IS NOT NULL AND check_out IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'OK'
        WHEN date_mark IS NOT NULL AND check_in IS NOT NULL AND check_in > '09:15:00'
            THEN 'LATE'
        ELSE 'LEFT'
        END AS CONDITION
FROM CTE C
LEFT JOIN ReportAssistence RA ON C.DATES = date_mark
WHERE ISNULL(RA.cod_personal, @cod_personal) = @cod_personal
```

And the result will be

```
+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| cod_personal | cod_schedule | date_mark  | check_in | check_out | CONDITION |
+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-01 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-02 | NULL     | 18:10:00  | LEFT IN   |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-03 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-04 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-05 | NULL     | 18:02:00  | LEFT IN   |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-06 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-07 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-08 | 09:20:00 | NULL      | LATE      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-09 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-10 | NULL     | 18:04:00  | LEFT IN   |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-11 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-12 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-13 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-14 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-15 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-16 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-17 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-18 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | NULL         | 2017-03-19 | NULL     | NULL      | LEFT      |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-20 | 08:56:00 | 18:53:00  | OK        |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-21 | 08:52:00 | 18:10:00  | OK        |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-22 | 08:56:00 | 18:09:00  | OK        |
|           39 | 1            | 2017-03-23 | NULL     | 18:05:00  | LEFT IN   |
+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Yes, But I thought instead of looping & Recursive CTE it is better to use the existed table in the database.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just wondering, since this appears to be an assignment for some kind of educational database, whether or not it's safe to assume the author can/should be querying a system database.

Comment: Your answer works for me, but when I run my stored procedure, I send the dates as a string, how would I change the variables from date to varchar?
DECLARE @cod_personal INT = 39
    ,@startDate VARCHAR(10)= '2017/03/01'
    ,@endDate VARCHAR(10)= '2017/03/23'

Comment: send date type. or cast them to date using `CAST` @LiXang

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you helped me a lot by solving this problem, @ShakeerMirza the truth is I only program in java, and sql server I am obsolete. hehehehe thank you x(infinite)

Comment: Some way to exclude the days "Sundays" on that table??

Comment: @LiXang Yes you can.. Put one more condition in WHERE clause `WHERE ISNULL(RA.cod_personal, @cod_personal) = @cod_personal AND DATENAME(DW,C.DATES) <>'Sunday'`

Comment: @ShakeerMirza can help me on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619279/sql-server-select-all-days-range-from-complete-table-if-no-data-exists-for-som
is same, but need complete table, exception select cod_personal, only got all tablet from range dates

Answer (score 1):

@ShakeerMirza answer is right - here's an alternative CTE that doesn't require querying the master database to build a table of consecutive dates. (Adding this as an answer instead of a comment because the formatting is important.)

```
;with cod (dates)
as
(
    select cast(@startdate as date) as dates
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dates) as next_dt
    from cod
    where DATEADD(day, 1, dates) < @enddate
)
select * from cod
```

Answer (score 0):

STORE PROCEDURE DONE!!!

It was necessary that the dates be entered as text in my case,
because i use for java and i have problem for cast date.util to date.sql on my POO and Interfaces

```
USE [DB_Demo1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[showMeReportAssistance]    Script Date: 5/04/2017 12:36:46 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[showMeReportAssistance]

@cod_personal INT,
@startDate VARCHAR(10),
@endDate VARCHAR(10)

as
BEGIN
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, number, CONVERT(datetime, @startDate, 103)) AS DATES
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE TYPE = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(DD, number, CONVERT(datetime, @startDate, 103)) <= CONVERT(datetime, @endDate, 103)
    )
SELECT ISNULL(RA.cod_personal, @cod_personal) AS cod_personal
    ,cod_schedule
    ,DATES AS date_mark
    ,check_in
    ,check_out
    ,CASE 
        WHEN date_mark IS NULL
            THEN 'LEFT'
        WHEN date_mark IS NOT NULL AND check_in IS NULL
            THEN 'LEFT IN'
        WHEN date_mark IS NOT NULL AND check_in IS NOT NULL AND check_out IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'OK'
        WHEN date_mark IS NOT NULL AND check_in IS NOT NULL AND check_in > '09:15:00'
            THEN 'LATE'
        ELSE 'LEFT'
        END AS CONDITION
FROM CTE C
LEFT JOIN ReportAssistence RA ON C.DATES = date_mark
WHERE ISNULL(RA.cod_personal, @cod_personal) = @cod_personal
END
```